How to non-uniform scale this mesh?
I am trying to widen the flat face.


maybe try in Sculpt mode, mask the parts that you don't want to move? You can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

In edit mode, press O to enter Proportional Edit mode, then use the mouse wheel while transforming to change the falloff. Docs

Or what nobody mentioned so far: to scale only on Y and Z axis in this case, press S to start scaling and then Shift+X to lock the X axis. Combine this with the Proportional Edit mode which @Jakemoyo mentioned to have a smoother transition between scaled and non-scaled parts. (If you wonder, the difference to Jakemoyo's approach is that in his example the object will also be scaled on X, what you maybe don't want).
